Gnome-Terminal extremely slow to start
I recently upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10 and now GNOME Terminal is extremely slow to start after system boot. GNOME Console is the same way. GNOME settings are affected as well.
Takes about 30 seconds, and looking at output of strace it's waiting for a forked process.
Once it starts up once, subsequent starts are faster.
My system specs are pretty good - Intel Core i7 12700, 32 GB of RAM, NVME's.
NVIDIA 4080 with the proprietary driver, X11, dual 4K 27" displays.
Manjaro with the same GNOME version on the same hardware is not affected.
I created a brand new test user in my Ubuntu setup and the same slowness issue exists there.
Has anyone seen this? I've reported the bug to Ubuntu but haven't received a response.

Edit: gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.54.0 using VTE 0.78.0 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD

Edit: Wayland session is not affected, GNOME Terminal / Console / Settings start up instantly even after a reboot.
But I can't use Wayland because XWayland apps are blurry (GNOME has had a merge request to fix this for 3 years now, still not done). I use apps like Android Studio and GoLand daily, and need them to look sharp.

Does this happen under Wayland?

Run gnome-terminal --version to give more information. I am seeing gnome-shell is being held back on 24.10 currently, but gnome-terminal is not one of them

Sounds like launchpad bug 2042301 Windows are Slow to Open after Login under X session.  Join the bug by clicking on the "Does this affect me?" icon in the upper left corner. Comment on your hardware and release, as well as confirm the journalctl errors found by others.

Yes I have same errors in the journal under X11 - added them to the Ubuntu bug report on Launchpad
